# Expected value of $\max \{n-q,q-1\}$

Tags: probability

When is the  expected value of $\max \{n-q,q-1\}$ , where $n$ is a fixed number and $q$ is in $[0,n]$ , so $\max\{n-q,q-1 \}$ is in $[\frac{n}{2},n]$, equal to $\frac{\frac{n}{2}+n}{2}=\frac{3n}{4}$?

In general, when is the expected value of $x \in [a,b]$ equal to $\frac{a+b}{2}$ ?

Does it hold if $q$  is uniform on $[0,n]$?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking...

Comment: When is the expectancy of $x \in [a,b]$ equal to $\frac{a+b}{2}$ ? @Math1000

Comment: What is "expectancy"? Expected value? You should consider rewriting your question, I have read it several times and I simply cannot make sense of it...

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, I meant the expected value...

Comment: What is the distribution of $q$? Uniform on $[0,n]$?

Comment: Does it have to be known that $q$ is uniform on $[0,n]$ so that the expected value is as above?

Answer (score 2):

$$q\sim U(0,n),\ E[\max\{n-q,q-1\}] = \int_0^n\max\{n-q,q-1\}\left(\frac1n\right)\mathsf dq$$
If $A=\{q\  |\  n-q>q-1\}$,
$$E[\max\{n-q,q-1\}] = \frac1n \int_A(n-q)\mathsf dq + \frac1n \int_{A^c}(q-1)\mathsf dq$$
Specifically, we are interested in the boundary $2q = n+1$, where $2q < n+1\implies q\in A$.
Let $b = \frac{n+1}{2}$, then
$$E[\max\{n-q,q-1\}] = \frac1{2n}\big([n^2 -(n-b)^2] + [(n-1)^2 - (b-1)^2]\big)$$
$$= \frac1{2n}\big(n^2 + (n-1)^2 - \frac{1}{4}((2n - (n+1))^2 + (n+1-2)^2\big)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2n}\big(n^2 + (n-1)^2 -\frac12 (n-1)^2\big)=\frac{1}{4n}\big(2n^2 + (n-1)^2\big)\neq \frac{3n}{4}.$$